# Having trouble using ISNUMBER function for cells containing formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to identify if an issue has already been queried.

Column R has my True/false formula which is pasted below, and `Column S` has my query text which contains  several sentences (note that the query text is generated by a formula). There is also an array list in another worksheet called `All_Discreps` and this represents the more official list of queries sent in the past.  So I need to compare my list in `column S` with the more official list and see if there is a match. If a match, then I print the message `already queried` in `column R`.

Formula in `column R`:

```
IF(AND(S7 <> "", ISNUMBER(MATCH(S7, All_Discreps!$J$1:$J$591, 0))), "already queried", "")
```

The issue I come across is that the text in `column S` is not seen as matching the official list in the other worksheet, apparently due to the formula which generates the text in `column S`.  If I overwrite the formula in `column S`, with say "hello 123", and then also type the same thing "hello 123" in the other worksheet, the match is recognized and this shows I have a basically valid formula in `column R`.  But there must be something else I need to do   to get this to work.

Comment: There may be whitespace at the end of the data you are querying, try running the trim() function on both columns; you may also have conflicting data types which can interfere with the match function, make sure both columns are the same data type.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried the trim function, as in ISNUMBER(MATCH(trim(S7), All_Discreps, etc. but it did not work.  I also tried adding trim() within the formula of cell S7 itself.   Both cells being compared have the same data type (General).  So I believe it is something else, but we're very close to getting this.  I am breaking the formula within S7 down into smaller pieces to see if it works.

Comment: for example, 1) I simplified the S7 formula to say just "The " and then I typed the same thing in the other worksheet (All_Discreps), and it recognized the match (good!).  then 2) I added in the first piece of dynamic code following the "The" and carefully typed the same text within the other worksheet, and it did not match unfortunately.   then 3) to decipher if the problem is with the programmatic code, I included just the first piece of code in cell S7 and put the same text in the other worksheet, and it recognized the match (that's good!), but why doesn't it all work together?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the length!!   anything above 255 chars will not work.  So I will next figure out how to work with the length.

Answer (score 2):

I found another discussion which addresses my issue.  The root cause of my issue relates to the 255 character limitation of the Match function.

See:  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184721
Or search for "Excel MATCH 255 character limit" to see other postings on this. Some people give 255 char limit... others say 256 char.  The main idea is the TRUE function will allow it include more than 255 characters (for example, as much as 113,000 characters according to one posting [which I cannot find at the moment].

So the formula (for cell R7) which works for me is:
IF(AND(S7 <> "", ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(All_Discreps!$J$1:$J$591 = S7, 0), 0))), "Already queried", "")